# 301 Redirect ALL none existing links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, redirecttoaction

I have had a look around at other posts but since i'm not a .htaccess wizard i can't quite figure out how to change the code to fit my needs.

Basically i have a holding page. page for a site i am building and just want any link that doesn't exist to be redirected back the the holding page.

I imagine it goes something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
#if not root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
#redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You code will create an infinite loop (you are rewriting to the same url), try this instead (and make sure that the `holdingpage.php` does exists, or your get an infinite loop):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
#If the requested file does not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Redirect to the holding page
RewriteRule . http://www.example.co.uk/holdingpage.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't working for me... could you think of any other reason that this might not be working?

I am still just getting a 404 page. 

I have done a simple redirect to say if a someone types in /test/ it redirects to www.example.com/apples and this works. So it isn't a configuration problem. I imagine it must be purely syntax...

Comment: can you post what is on your htaccess file